# Callback system for events in a window

Tags: c++, event-handling, pointers, callback

I have written a simple window event capture wrapper that gets events that happen to the window, and can be checked anywhere in the program through a global class. I wanted to be able to create a callback anywhere in the program with any event that I have asked to be checked. To hold the data that is returned from the events, I have used a pointer that is allocated whenever an event occurs, so I can grab the data returned later on in the program.

I don't want to use templates to hold the data since that would require a lot of objects to be created, or a lot of vectors for each specific event that I want. I find this to be too clunky, and I wanted a clean, simple solution.

Data that is captured

```
struct windowEventData
    {
        void *data = nullptr;
        std::string id;
        sf::Event::EventType event;

        bool polled = false;
    };
```

Window Event Manager

```
class windowEventManager
    {
        private:
            std::vector<windowEventData> _subscribedEvents;

        public:
            void subscribe(const std::string &id, sf::Event::EventType event);
            void pollEvent(sf::Event event);
            void clearEvents();

            template<typename T>
            T* hasEventPolled(const std::string &id);

            ~windowEventManager();
    };
```

Grabbing and setting the pointer

```
void windowEventManager::pollEvent(sf::Event event)
    {
        for (auto &eventCheck : _subscribedEvents)
            {
                if (eventCheck.event == event.type)
                    {
                        switch (event.type)
                            {
                                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                                case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
                                    eventCheck.data = new sf::Event::KeyEvent(event.key);
                                    break;
                                case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                                case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
                                    eventCheck.data = new sf::Mouse::Button(event.mouseButton.button);
                                    break;
                                case sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved:
                                case sf::Event::MouseWheelScrolled:
                                    eventCheck.data = new bool(true);
                                    break;
                                case sf::Event::TextEntered:
                                    eventCheck.data = new sf::String(event.text.unicode);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        eventCheck.polled = true;
                    }
            }
    }
```

I clear events before each poll, and in the destructor so I don't have memory leaks/too much on the heap

```
void windowEventManager::clearEvents()
    {
        for (auto &eventCheck : _subscribedEvents)
            {
                if (eventCheck.data)
                    {
                        delete eventCheck.data;
                        eventCheck.data = nullptr;
                    }
                eventCheck.polled = false;
            }
    }
```

Finding out if an event has occured

```
template<typename T>
inline T *windowEventManager::hasEventPolled(const std::string &id)
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(_subscribedEvents.begin(), _subscribedEvents.end(), [id] (windowEventData &dat) { return dat.id == id && dat.polled; });
        if (it != _subscribedEvents.end())
            {
                return static_cast<T*>((*it).data);
            }

        return nullptr;
    }
```

Is my use of a `void*` proper? I figured I could use a union as well for this, but I would rather see if using a pointer would be a good solution.

Comment: You'll have to provide the class definition for `windowEventManager`, in particular what is the type of `_subscribedEvents`? In case it's `std::vector<windowEventData>`, I think you'll find that `delete eventCheck.data;` doesn't even compile, does it?

Comment: Added the class definition, I knew I was forgetting something. I am currently using this in my program, and it does happen to compile and run without hitches.

Comment: I would start looking for ways to add more certainty.  So instead of void * data, and if you truly cannot know the type(s) at compile time, I would go with something like boost::any.  If you know the types at compile time something like boost::variant can convey that effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I do NOT recommend doing this**

I would do this somehow different. I'm not sure why you need an `id` at all. A listener/receiver is interested in a specific type of event, isn't it? If you want to follow your "poll and get" flow, all you have to do is to store your events somehow.

If you're using c++11 (and I guess you are), things are easier, variadic template arguments are so good. This whole thing could be done totally different, but I'm trying to follow and adjust your code. So here comes I've came up with:

I dropped the whole `id` thing and I'm using the event type only. I created a base `EventDataBase` class. This can be used to get the real data from the event data object.

```
class EventDataBase
{
public:
    const sf::Event::EventType event;

    EventDataBase(sf::Event::EventType event)
        : event(event)
    { }
    virtual ~EventDataBase() { }

    template <class T>
    T* getData()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(getDataPtr());
    }

protected:
    virtual void* getDataPtr() = 0;
};
```

Then a simple template class is created which holds the actual data:

```
template <class T, typename... Args>
class EventData : public EventDataBase
{
public:
    EventData(sf::Event::EventType event, Args... args)
        : EventDataBase(event),
          data(args...)
    { }

private:
    T data;

    void* getDataPtr() override { return &data; }
};
```

With the variadic template args the constructor of your actual data can have any parameters (but that must match!). Another solution would be to pass an existing `T` object to the `EventData` class but that means the `T` must be copy-constructable:

```
template <class T>
class EventData : public EventDataBase
{
public:
    EventData(sf::Event::EventType event, const T& data)
        : EventDataBase(event),
          data(data)
    { }

private:
    T data;

    void* getDataPtr() override { return &data; }
};
```

Then you can use typedefs if you wish. I'm using the variadic-template-args solution from now, but you can adjust your code.

```
typedef EventData<sf::Event::SimpleEvent> SimpleEventData;
// downside is that the Args must match the parameters of the KeyEvent's constructor
typedef EventData<sf::Event::KeyEvent, int> KeyEventData;
```

I'm not sure if you have only one `EventManager` or not but I guess you have only one and you call the `pollEvent` function in the application's main loop. I ignored the subscribe functionality, but that can be added easily.

```
class EventManager
{
public:
    // called in the application's main loop
    void pollEvent(const sf::Event& event)
    {
        // if you want to check if anyone is interested in this event, do it here
        // ...

        EventDataBase* eventData = nullptr;

        switch (event.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Simple:
            eventData = new SimpleEventData(event.type);
            break;

        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
        case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
            eventData = new KeyEventData(event.type, 10 /* key code */);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (eventData)
            polledEvents.push_back(eventData);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T* hasEvent(sf::Event::EventType event)
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(polledEvents.begin(), polledEvents.end(),
                               [event](EventDataBase* data) { return data->event == event; });

        if (it == polledEvents.end())
            return nullptr;

        return (*it)->getData<T>();
    }

    // TODO: clearEvents() function is basically the same
    // you have to delete the EventDataBase objects
    // and clear the polledEvents vector

private:
    // you can use a map<EventType, EventDataBase*>
    // if only one event is allowed per type
    // but in a real application that's not true (eg. KeyPressed)
    typedef std::vector<EventDataBase*> Events;

    Events polledEvents;
};
```

And the usage:

```
EventManager mgr;
mgr.pollEvent(sf::Event(sf::Event::Simple));
mgr.pollEvent(sf::Event(sf::Event::KeyPressed));
mgr.pollEvent(sf::Event(sf::Event::KeyReleased));

sf::Event::SimpleEvent* simple = mgr.hasEvent<sf::Event::SimpleEvent>(sf::Event::Simple);
sf::Event::KeyEvent* keyPressed = mgr.hasEvent<sf::Event::KeyEvent>(sf::Event::KeyPressed);
sf::Event::KeyEvent* keyReleased = mgr.hasEvent<sf::Event::KeyEvent>(sf::Event::KeyReleased);
```

**Questions:**

- What happens when you have multiple event with the same type (eg. KeyPressed)? (You can modify the `hasEvent` function to fill a vector instead of return with the first matched element)
- What happens when you get an event with a wrong type? (eg. `hasEvent<Event::KeyEvent>(EventType::Simple)`)
- Do you really want to allow the hasEvent caller to modify the event data? If not, you should return (or fill) `const T*` instead of `T*`
- What happens if the hasEvent caller delete the returned object? That's not even heap allocated! Instant crash I guess...

So I'm not sure if this is the best way you can do it. The `hasEvent` function is dangerous. What if I try to get a `sf::Event::KeyEvent` with a `sf::Event::Simple` type? The data is simply "converted" (casted) to the desired type. And eg. if I try to modify the data... You can imagine. Consider the following example.

```
// invalid cast, but it's done
sf::Event::KeyEvent* keyPressed = mgr.hasEvent<sf::Event::KeyEvent>(sf::Event::Simple);
// modify the data
keyPressed->key = 0;

// ... random crash
// because the `keyPressed` points to a bigger memory area than it should
// sizeof(KeyEvent) > sizeof(SimpleEvent) !!
```

**A better approach**

[...] would be message-based. I mean real message based. A class could subscribe to the manager with its object pointer and a function. That function would be called when an event occurs. So your code should not have to call "hasEvent" everywhere but instead the registered function would be called automatically. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
// in the manager

// define the events
Event<int> onKeyPressed;
Event<int> onKeyReleased;

// when an application creates an event
switch (event.type)
{
case EventType::KeyPressed:
    onKeyPressed(event.key);
    break;

    // ...
}

// your listener/receiver code:

// define the handler function
void callThisOnKeyPressed(int key)
{
    // handle key pressed event
}

// register to event
manager.onKeyPressed.subscribe(this, &MyClassName::callThisOnKeyPressed);
```

In c++11 this can be implemented easily with some template magic. :)

**Edit**

I totally forget to mention the object pooling. Constantly calling new and delete is not too memory-friendly. You can use a custom memory manager (placement new) to solve this issue.

**Edit 2**

You can actually check if the event type is valid for the specific event data with a template "checking" function, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool isTypeAllowed(sf::Event::EventType type);

template <>
bool isTypeAllowed<sf::Event::KeyEvent>(sf::Event::EventType type)
{
    return (type == sf::Event::KeyPressed || type == sf::Event::KeyReleased);
}
```

You can use this function to check if the specified `EventType` is valid for the `T` event data type. You can do this check in the `hasEvent` function:

```
template <typename T>
T* hasEvent(sf::Event::EventType event)
{
    if (!isTypeAllowed<T>(event))
        return nullptr;

    auto it = std::find_if(polledEvents.begin(), polledEvents.end(),
                           [event](EventDataBase* data) { return data->event == event; });

    if (it == polledEvents.end())
        return nullptr;

    return (*it)->getData<T>();
}

// or the collection variant:

template <typename T>
bool hasEvent(sf::Event::EventType event, std::vector<T*>& result)
{
    result.clear();

    if (!isTypeAllowed<T>(event))
        return false;

    for (auto& e : polledEvents)
    {
        if (e->event == event)
            result.push_back(e->getData<T>());
    }

    return !result.empty();
}
```

Comment: I figured someone would tell me to use a message-based system. I have used one in the past, and I didn't like how it turned out. But if it's better that what I have, I probably implemented it wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: Something just came to my mind about type checking, so I edited my answer, you can see the addition in the "Edit 2" section.  I still recommend a message-based event system, you have to implement it once and can be used everywhere in your project. (Please note that there might be better solutions than I've posted). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
delete eventCheck.data;
```

This line invokes undefined behavior, because you aren't allowed to call `delete` on an incomplete type (and certainly not on `void`). Both GCC and Clang warn on this line:

```
(clang++)
prog.cc:4:5: warning: cannot delete expression with pointer-to-'void' type 'void *' [-Wdelete-incomplete]
    delete p;
    ^      ~

(g++)
prog.cc:4:12: warning: deleting 'void*' is undefined
     delete p;
            ^
```

Anyway, it won't do what you want (whatever that might be).

For an open set of types, the type-safe way to do what you're trying to do is to use *type erasure*, as seen in library containers such as `std::function<void(void)>`. (Shameless plug for [my CppCon 2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKG1m2NkANM&index=1&list=PLXTVlgmc2KcD3mgkZfrq3jJl8RNaAz-lp) — type erasure is covered starting at 23m00s.) This kind of type-erasure is easy to implement yourself from scratch in about 20 lines of code.

For a closed set of types, you might see whether your compiler of choice supports C++17 `std::variant` and/or Boost `boost::variant`; you can use the `visit` function to perform an operation on a variant in a type-safe way, and of course you wouldn't even need `delete` at that point because you wouldn't be using pointers, just plain old value semantics. If you can't use Boost, then I *don't* recommend trying to implement `variant` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will have to find out why my compiler didn't warn me of the undefined behavior. I will probably use std::variant when my compiler updates